# Pendulum equation

Tags: calculus

If we denote by $\phi^{-1}$ the inverse of the function that satisfied the equation $\phi'=\sqrt{(1-k^2\sin^2\phi)}$, we obtain
$$
\left(  \phi^{-1}\right)  ^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  =\frac{1}{\sqrt
{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}t}},
$$
hence, (noting $u=\sin t):$
$$
\phi^{-1}\left(  x\right)  =\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}t}%
}\operatorname*{dt}=\int_{0}^{\sin x}\frac{\operatorname*{du}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}%
}\sqrt{1-k^{2}u^{2}}}.
$$
Finally
$$
 x =\int_{0}^{\sin \phi(x)}\frac{\operatorname*{du}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}%
}\sqrt{1-k^{2}u^{2}}}.
$$
Maybe it is obvious, but why the conclusion is true?

Comment: I think it's because $x = \phi^{-1}(\phi)$

Comment: Alternatively, one may treat your differential equation as a separable one for $x$, and you will get the same integral representation.